# Conjugate complex coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative

This is the question and the problem is we didn't take multivariable calculus to understand these steps, where did it come from? When I search multivariable chain rule I get a different result than this, can anyone tell me how the answer makes sense provided that I know about partial derivatives but we haven't taken multivariable functions and how they're differentiated in this way, this is a complex variable course.

[image]

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2945446/289217 . You'll have to deal with multivariable calculus to understand complex calculus.

Comment: thanks i'll try to understand